# How to represent pivot table (with extra data on it) in datomic?

Tags: clojure, datomic, datalog

I realise that we don't need ordinary pivot tables in datomic because we can just pick one side of the relationship and put a `:db.cardinality/many` attribute on there (being sure to model the relationship [in one direction only](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/best-practices.html#one-direction-only)).

The next thing I encounter in converting from sql is a pivot table that also stores an attribute on the relationship, like:

```sql
series_subscriptions
  user_id    int
  series_id  int
  expires_at timestamp
```

I was wondering what the options are to model this in datomic.
I notice there are some things in schema that I don't understand the reason for yet, or appropriate usage, like composite tuples, components.

One option though is elevate the pivot to its own entity so it can handle the extra attribute:

```clj
:series-subscription/user       ; ref, one
:series-subscription/series     ; ref, one
:series-subscription/timestamp  ; timestamp, one
```

But the above seems a bit wrong. Doing it like that means in datalog the join would no longer be implicit, which would appear to be a loss. Wonder if there are better options.

Comment: I would do it exactly as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Heterogeneous tuples are the more concise way to achieve this since their introduction in July 2019.

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61386621/datomic-many-to-many-with-data-on-the-relationship).

The July 2019 update to Datomic contained a lot of different features all at once and usage is not yet well documented online, though the docs do explain it (not much is needed to explain it - a case of simple but, perhaps, not easy). Note it's specifically ***heterogeneous*** tuples that solve the concern here, it would work to ignore the other types of tuples to get started for this use case.