# Datomic cardinality many attribute (vs. sql pivot table) - no downsides?

Tags: clojure, datomic, datalog

Is it an issue in any way that a `card many` attribute may have a huge number of values? (say 10^6)

I think the intuition/concern here is that we definitely don't want equivalent of a `select *` on the entity creeping in anywhere.

Of course, the datoms making up a card many are clearly **[stored individually](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/entities.html)**, so I suspect this simply isn't an issue. However I just wanted to be sure.

Coming from sql, the pivot is clearly a separate table and can be treated as such.

So, I guess it depends entirely on the entity/pull apis that actually assemble the datoms, and/or perhaps on datalog itself (Background: I haven't used the datomic apis for real yet, though I have done the excellent [learn datalog](http://www.learndatalogtoday.org/) tutorial - my current task is translating a few sql schemas  i have into datomic, to get started).

I'd like to know if that is simply not a problem in any of the pull or entity apis, that such an attribute can be easily excluded from a result set in effectively all cases, or is there any drawback of a highly numerous card many attribute to be aware of?

Comment: It might be worth adding that it is possible to ["reify" a `card many` ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61064412/how-to-represent-pivot-table-with-extra-data-on-it-in-datomic) into its own entity, which it seems one would want to do in order to put any attributes onto the relationship.  So, it seems there is a choice available whether or not to use a card many or not depending on requirements.

Comment: Rich actually [put it like this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/datomic/QmhsIL7tZwI/7oGaiEXKtz4J): "All facts are stored separately, as the fact that M manages A is a separate fact from that M manages B, with independent assertion/retraction times. The set of people M manages is derived from the facts, just as in the real world, it isn't a concrete thing. Deriving the set is extremely efficient."